# Excluding duplicates in cat / ls result

Tags: linux, duplicates, cat, ls

I have hundreds of lines in a file with the same ending.

My workout (same result):

```
$ cat x.txt | sort -u
$ cat x.txt | sort -u | uniq -u
$ cat x.txt | sort -u | awk '!a[$0]++'

media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2437.ts
media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2438.ts
media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2439.ts
media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2440.ts
media_w950159543_b1344100_sleng_2439.ts
media_w950159543_b1344100_sleng_2440.ts
media_w950159543_b1344100_sleng_2441.ts
..........so on and on.................
```

I want the result to become something like this:

```
media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2437.ts
media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2438.ts
media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2439.ts
media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2440.ts
media_w950159543_b1344100_sleng_2441.ts
..........so on and on.................
```

Comment: You've given your current output, and your desired output. Can give us the input and describe what lines you'd like filtered out and how you want the output sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the array with the 4 digit numbers and so:

```
cat x.txt | sort -u | awk -F [\._] '{ if (a[$5]=="") { a[$5]=$0 } } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";for (i in a) { print a[i] } }'
```

Set . and _ as the field delimiter and then set up an array a with the 5th delimiter piece (4 digit code) as the index and the line as the value. At the end, sort in array index order and print each value of the array.

Comment: Thank you. Btw, the result only show first line: `media_w2089898193_b1344100_sleng_2437.ts`

Comment: Apologies. The - field delimiter should have been _ I've just changed it

Comment: Still with same result. You also forgot a single quote in last code. Thank you.

Comment: I had forgot the $ in front of the 5's!!!! Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne '/.*(\d+)/; print if !$seen{$1}++;' in_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.

`/.*(\d+)/` : Capture into `$1` the last stretch of 1 or more digits.
`print if !$seen{$1}++;` : Print only the first occurrence of each captured stretch of digits.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)